# Catalan numbers counts the number of balanced expressions of 3 diffarent types $\{,(,[$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, catalan-numbers

I got the following puzzle -

> count the number of different sequences with

$r$ -  "$($" and $r$ -  "$)$",

$k$ - "$[$" and $k$ -  "$]$",

$n$ - "{" and $n$ - "}"

I know that this is solved with Catalan numbers and know that the number of balanced sequences with "(" and ")" is $${\frac {1}{n+1}}{2n \choose n}$$

But how to solve it when I got 3 **types** of objects?

Edit:
((({)[])}) is valid expression.

Thanks for any Tips and guidance...

Comment: Are you serious that $([)]$ is valid?

Comment: Why doesn't the answer involves $r$ or $k$? Can you explain better?

Comment: @ZachTeitler yes :)

Answer (score 2):

There are $c_r \times c_k \times c_n$ triples of balanced (), [], and {} expressions of the appropriate lengths.  Now you have to interleave them.  There are $2(r+k+n)$ positions, $2r$ of which have to be occupied by (), and so on. Thus, there are $\binom{2(r+k+n)}{2r}$ ways to place the () symbols.  Having done that, there are $2(k+n)$ positions, $2k$ of of which have to be [].  Surely you can finish from here?

The key here is that the 3 symbol sets are disjoint, so given one of your expressions you can uniquely parse it into the 3 balanced (), [], and {} expressions.

For example, suppose $r=k=1$ and $n=0$.  The Catalan numbers are all 1 in this case, so in this case the question boils down to counting the number of ways of interleaving () with [].  There are 4 ($2r+2k+2n=4$) positions in this case, two of which will end up holding () and 2 holding [].  Thus, letting 0 and 1 stand for "this position will hold part of ()" and "...part of []" respectively, we have patterns 0011, 0101, 0110,  1001, 1010, and 1100:  six in all, counted by $\binom{4}{2}$, resulting in interleavings ()[], ([)], ([]), [()], [(]) and $\text{[]()}$.  You get to specify an arbitrary size $2r$ subset of the available $2r+2k+2n$ positions (in $\binom{2r+2k+2n}{2r}$ ways  to fill in your () pattern in $c_r$ ways.  Then you get to pick an arbitrary size $2k$ subset of the unoccupied $2k+2n$ positions, in $\binom{2k+2n}{2k}$ ways and fill those positions with [] expressions in $c_k$ ways.  Now you have only $2n$ remaining slots, with no futher choices of subsets, but $c_n$ ways to fill them with {} expresions.  The interleaving part of the problem is a "subset counting" problem, not a "gaps" or "stars and bars" problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, But that's excellently what I dont understand, how can I "mix" the $c_{r}$ with $c_{k}$ with $c_{n}$

Comment: I have fixed a typo in my post and added more hint material.

Comment: I think I understand  so the final answer would be : $\frac{1}{r+1}\cdot\left(\begin{array}{c}2r\\r\end{array}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{array}{c}2r+1\\2k\end{array}\right)\frac{1}{k+1}\cdot\left(\begin{array}{c}2k\\k\end{array}\right)
\cdot\left(\begin{array}{c}2r+2k+1\\2m\end{array}\right)\frac{1}{m+1}\cdot\left(\begin{array}{c}2m\\m\end{array}\right)$?

Comment: Not exactly.  I get the product of the 3 Catalan numbers and $\binom{2r+2k+2n}{2r}\binom{2k+2n}{2k}$.  This last factor is the same as $(2r+2k+2n)!/((2r)!{2k)!(2n)!$.

Comment: can You please explain me what is wrong with my logic - I assign 2k "[","]" to 2r+1 gaps (between 2r "(",")") and then I am doing it again with "{","}"

Comment: I will edit my answer.